# Remmina says Lost connection to the RDP server

Tags: remmina

It was working fine until this morning, I have tried deleting "known hosts" file, uninstalling and reinstalling the app as well. Happy to try out alternative software.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].